# Getting coordinates for glFrustum

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, openframeworks

I just started reading about `OpenGL` topics, specifically about [`Viewing`](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) for my current needs. I am trying to understand `glFrustum` for a perspective projection of objects that I have drawn on the screen and as I understand `glFrustum` would make the farther objects smaller than the nearer objects.
I am using `openFrameworks` here for drawing objects such as `Image`/`Box` etc. and here's a short example of what I am trying to do:

*openFrameworks draw method*

```
draw()
{
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 500.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

sceneImage.draw(0,0,ofGetWidth(), ofGetHeight()); //draw an image on the screen with window's width and dheight 
}
```

With the above glFrustum, I am just trying to to clip the image and see a particular portion of the image for an initial test. I am not sure about what those arguments of `glFrustum` actually are even as I read about `glFrustum` from above link of Red book. The arguments of course are `left, right, bottom, top, near, far`, but how is `1.0` or `1.0` being calculated? I was expecting screen coordinates to go in there and tried something like `glFrustum(100, 984, 100, 668,3, 500)` but nothing appeared on the screen. How are those arguments for `glFrustum` calculated?

Comment: a think that you might want to read: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I got your question right, if not just let me know, but if you're asking "*how you should calculate the `glFrustum` arguments*" this is how:

Its actually all about the aspect ratio and the fov. Usually you're going to find information about how to make the perspective matrix using the vertical fov, but some times you'll want to use the horizontal fov. So heres what I came up with, I don't use `glFrustum` but I think you can simply switch my `perspective` function with it and it should still work:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// set a perspective frustum (right hand)
// (left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void perspective(float l, float r, float b, float t, float n, float f)
{
    m_projection.identity();

    m_projection[0]  =  2.0f * n / (r - l);
    m_projection[2]  =  (r + l) / (r - l);
    m_projection[5]  =  2.0f * n / (t - b);
    m_projection[6]  =  (t + b) / (t - b);
    m_projection[10] = -(f + n) / (f - n);
    m_projection[11] = -(2.0f * f * n) / (f - n);
    m_projection[14] = -1.0f;
    m_projection[15] =  0.0f;

    update();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// set a symmetric perspective frustum
// ((vertical, degrees) field of view, (width/height) aspect ratio, near, far)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void perspective_vertical(float fov, float aspect, float front, float back)
{
    fov = DEG_TO_RAD(fov);                      // transform fov from degrees to radians

    float tangent = tanf(fov / 2.0f);               // tangent of half vertical fov
    float height = front * tangent;                 // half height of near plane
    float width = height * aspect;                  // half width of near plane

    perspective(-width, width, -height, height, front, back);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// set a symmetric perspective frustum
// ((horizontal, degrees) field of view, (width/height) aspect ratio, near, far)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void perspective_horizontal(float fov, float aspect, float front, float back)
{
    fov = DEG_TO_RAD(fov);                      // transform fov from degrees to radians
    fov = 2.0f * atanf(tanf(fov * 0.5f) / aspect);  // transform from horizontal fov to vertical fov

    float tangent = tanf(fov / 2.0f);               // tangent of half vertical fov
    float height = front * tangent;                 // half height of near plane
    float width = height * aspect;                  // half width of near plane

    perspective(-width, width, -height, height, front, back);
}
```

And the helping macros:

```
#define PI_OVER_180 0.0174532925199432957692369076849f
#define 180_OVER_PI 57.2957795130823208767981548141f

#define DEG_TO_RAD(x) (x * PI_OVER_180)
#define RAD_TO_DEG(x) (x * 180_OVER_PI)
```

The code is mostly commented and should make sense without having to further explain it. The parameters should be something along the lines of:

```
perspective_horizontal(85.0f /* fov of 85 degrees */, (float)width/height, 0.001f /* using near of 3.0f is kinda too much, just don't use 0.0f */, 1000.0f)
```

If you want to go more in depth and actually see the numbers working you can put some break points or `printf` it to see how it works. The equivalent of 85 degrees horizontal is about 45 degrees vertical. Also, opengl uses column major, so if you end up using a matrix like this instead of `glFrustum` make sure you transpose it first.

---

EDIT (more about the comment below):

Lets take a window that is standard hd -400 pixels: (1920-400) wide and (1080-400) tall. The aspect ratio of a standard hd is 1.77 but -400 pixels version is (1920-400)/(1080-400) = 2.23.

Now calling the `perspective_horizontal` function with aspect ration of `(1920-400)/(1080-400)`, fov of `85` and putting a breakpoint before the `perspective(...)` call is going to give us the following variables:

- fov      float   0.778087676
- aspect   float   2.2352941
- front    float   0.00100000005
- back     float   100
- tangent  float   0.40993762
- height   float   0.000409937638
- width    float   0.000916331192

take note that 0.000916331192/0.000409937638 = 2.23529412052 and 0.778087676 radians to degrees = 44.5811399 degrees vertical which is the equivalent of 85 degrees horizontal.

Also calling  the `perspective_horizontal` function with aspect ration of `(1920-400)/(1080-400)`, fov of `105` instead is going to give us the following variables:

- fov      float   1.05568409
- aspect   float   2.2352941
- front    float   0.00100000005
- back     float   100
- tangent  float   0.583021879
- height   float   0.000583021902
- width    float   0.00130322541

take note again that 0.00130322541/0.000583021902 = 2.23529408677 and 1.05568409 radians to degrees = 60.4862429 degrees vertical which is the equivalent of 105 degrees horizontal.

As for the actual perspective matrix, I can't explain you how the formula works, but just imagine that there are magical unicorns in the gpu and if you feed them `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(inputPosition, 1.0f);` they're going to make some magic happen and its going to display beautiful things on the screen ;3.

---

`glFrustum` is also explained [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/124490-glFrustum-glOrtho), [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/353616-am-i-understanding-glfrustum-properly/), [here](http://robertokoci.com/world-view-projection-matrix-unveiled/), [here](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/), [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) and most importantly [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html).

Also theres one good explanation [here](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/perspective-projection-matrix/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to get an assymetric frustum because of which I chose to use `glFrustum`. Umm, I am still finding it a bit hard to understand the use of `FOV` in `glFrustum`'s explanation above since `glFrustum` accepts all the `coordinates` as the prototype explanation mentions. `glPerspective` as I understand is where I can explicitly specify `fov` for getting a perspective projection. But using `glFrustum` if I have still have to use `fov` to calculate the coordinates myself, how is it of utility?

Comment: `glFrustum` asks to mention the `left, right, bottom, top, near, far` coordinates and seeing that I specified `glFrustum(100, 984, 100, 668,3, 500)` where `(100,984)` are `left/right` screen coordinates for me, `(100,668)` are `bottom/top` screen coordiates for me. But obviously, there's a gap in my understaning here and nothing appears on the screen when I do this. With respect to the image in question which I was trying to clip (as in the post above) using the volume, how do I know what are the appropriate left, right, bottom, top coordinates so that I get my desired clipping of the image?

Comment: @user1240679 There's absolutely no reason to use such big numbers in glFrustum. What you're actually defining with those numbers is the aspect ratio and the frustum cone. Basically what you want is something along the lines of: left -2 right 2 top 1 bottom -1 if your screen is two times wide as is tall. But it needs to add in the fov too, so those numbers are not accurate. I'm going to expand on it at the end of my answer with some actual numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed! That's very relieving :) I have a follow up though not exactly related to above. -> As I specify the viewing volume with `glFrustum()`, I don't see a command that I seem to have given to draw the clipped scene around on the full screen coordinates (full screen width/height)? The projection matrix that I get from glFrustum is multiplied with the current matrix and the full scene is drawn as per the perspective projection?

Comment: In glFrustum, the prospective projection if for the objects that come in the viewing volume of frustum. As I set the viewing volume for an area that I want to project, is it possible to draw that projected objects on a separate region on the screen and not drawing the full screen here?

Comment: @user1240679 I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If you're asking whether you can draw the same scene from two different camera/frustum positions (like a first person then a top down view as a map or rear window) its going to be quite a bit of work. You're going to have to draw to a texture to achieve that. I'm not sure how the framework you're using works, but if you're interested in low level engine programming I'd suggest you drop the use of the framework and make it yourself. As for the manner in which you can achieve rendering of the scene from two different spots.. (1/2)

Comment: @user1240679 and two different aspect rations you're going to want to first make your projection matrix for the main window aspect ration, set the view matrix to the desired location, draw the scene, remake the projection matrix for the aspect ratio of the texture you're going to draw to (rear window, minimap etc) set the view matrix position to the desired location and draw to the texture(sprite). That's the gist of it. You may also want to drop the use of old opengls (-3.0) and focus on 3.0+, and I'd also suggest making your own matrices (projection, view, model) for more control. (2/2)

Comment: @user1240679 PS. By rear window I mostly meant rear-view mirror and by dropping opengl under 3.0 I meant not using `glMatrixMode` and instead giving the matrices directly to a shader. [This](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) is a nicely written *draw to texture* guide. (3/2)?!

Comment: `0.0174532925199432957692369076849f` This one is funny. You not only specify the number with precision exceeding that of x87 80-bit `long double`, but also then limit actual accuracy to `float`, which is usually IEEE 754 `binary32`, which needs maximum 9 decimal digits to reproduce its value. Same for the reciprocal. What's the point?